# How do I when to extend a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to add elements to a dynamically allocated `Flight` array to my program. As initialization of the `Flight* allFlights`, I set the size of the array as 1 and want to enlarge its size as I need to add more.

Such as:

```cpp
//Flight.cpp
Flight::Flight(int flightNumber, int rowNumber, int seatNumber)
{
    flightNo = flightNumber;
    rowNo = rowNumber;
    seatNo = seatNumber;
}
```

```cpp
//main.cpp
Flight* allFlights = new Flight[1];
```

I could not find a proper way to extend it as needed, so I tried to approach the problem by having 2 separate integer values as `numberOfFlights` and `capacityOfFlights`. I initialized `numberOfFlights` as 0 and `capacityOfFlights` to 1, and incremented `numberOfFlights` by 1 each time I added a new `Flight` and compared it to `capacityOfFlights` at each addition. If they were equal, I followed the steps below to extend my array.

```cpp
if (numberOfFlights != flightCapacity)
{
    Flight newFlight(flightNo, rowNo, seatNo); //Creating new flight object
    allFlights[numberOfFlights] = newFlight;
    numberOfFlights = numberOfFlights + 1;
}
else
{
    Flight newFlight(flightNo, rowNo, seatNo); //Creating new flight object
    //Reallocating dynamic array of allFlight to fit new flights
    flightCapacity = flightCapacity * 2;
    auto* temp = new Flight[flightCapacity];
    copy(allFlights, allFlights + numberOfFlights, temp);
    delete[] allFlights;
    allFlights = temp;

    //Adding the new flight to array
    allFlights[numberOfFlights] = newFlight;

    numberOfFlights = numberOfFlights + 1;
}
```

I know using `std::vector` could easily solve this problem, but in this case I'm not allowed to use it.

Is this a good way to solve the problem?  I personally find it wasteful of resources by using 2 `int` values and constantly checking the size by `if` statements.

Comment: *" I personally find it wasteful of resources"* - why? You need to know the size of the array one way or another.

Comment: Explicit use of `new` and `delete` [is not recommended](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-allocating-and-deallocating). Just use `std::vector` and inserting items will be trivial.

Comment: @MarekR I guess one of the requirements is no vectors, like the question says.

Comment: You can use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: *Is this a good way to solve the problem?* -- Create your own generic vector class, where you actually could learn how to properly put together such classes, instead of creating one-off classes such as `Flight`.  Then anytime you get the requirements that you "can't use vector", you have a ready-made vector class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code have duplicate parts. Increasing of array and putting data there can be separated.

```
       if (numberOfFlights == flightCapacity)
       {
          //Reallocating dynamic array of allFlight to fit new flights
          flightCapacity = flightCapacity * 2;
          auto* temp = new Flight[flightCapacity];
          copy(allFlights, allFlights + numberOfFlights, temp);
          delete[] allFlights;
          allFlights = temp;
       }
       Flight newFlight(flightNo, rowNo, seatNo); //Creating new flight object
       //Adding the new flight to array
       allFlights[numberOfFlights] = newFlight;
       numberOfFlights = numberOfFlights + 1;
```

Comment: If the OP can't use `std::vector` then he likely can't use `std::copy()` either. If so, use a manual loop instead: `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFlights; ++i) { temp[i] = allFlights[i]; }`

Comment: What if they can't use `for`? 

Comment: Then how is the OP expected to *ever* iterate through the available `Flight`s? Recursion? Ug.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `for(A; B; C) D;` can be written as `A; while(B) {D; C;}` expect for some difference like scopes and effect of `continue;`.

Comment: @MikeCAT What if they can't use `while`? 

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings There are some choices: recursion, `goto`, and [`setjmp / longjmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175221/is-it-allowed-to-do-longjmp-multiple-times-for-one-setjmp-call).

Comment: @MikeCAT What if they can't use branches at all? Completely linear code?

Comment: Think we might need an example of these fallback solutions Mike. Just in case. There are clearly some constraints involved in the assignment! Who knows where they might end...