# Using setjmp and longjmp with a local jmp_buf

Tags: c, language-lawyer, cpu-registers, local-variables, setjmp

In the case that a local `jmp_buf` is actually represented by registers rather than stack memory, is it possible for `setjmp` or `longjmp` to cause the contents of the local `jmp_buf` to be indeterminate when `setjmp` returns from a `longjmp`?

---

<sub>The suggested duplicate [Is it allowed to do longjmp() multiple times for one setjmp() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175221/is-it-allowed-to-do-longjmp-multiple-times-for-one-setjmp-call) asks in the context of a global variable. It was suggested since the answer explains that the variable is not modified in a way that would prevent it from being subsequently called, that sufficiently answers the question for a local variable too.
***However***, treatment of a local variable differs from a global variable. In particular, if the local `jmp_buf` variable is actually held in registers and not memory, restoration after `longjmp` may not render a reusable `jmp_buf` variable.</sub>

---

As an academic exercise, I was attempting to use `setjmp` as a substitute for `goto`. To keep the loop replacement local to the function, the `jmp_buf` used is also a local variable.

```
void foo (int n) {
    jmp_buf jb;
    volatile int i;
    i = setjmp(jb);
    if (i < n) {
        do_stuff(i);
        longjmp(jb, ++i);
    }
}
```

I understand that non-volatile local variables that have been modified between the `setjmp` call and the `longjmp` call are unspecified after `longjmp`. However, I was curious about the local `jmp_buf` variable itself, particularly in the case where the `jmp_buf` variable is represented by registers rather than memory on the stack.

It is unclear if `longjmp` itself can be considered something that may modify the local `jmp_buf` variable, and whether this means its contents are unspecified when `setjmp` returns after the call to `longjmp`.

I thought I could easily dispatch the issue by declaring `jb` to be `volatile`, but this triggered a warning (which I treat as an error):

```
... error: passing argument 1 of ‘_setjmp’ discards ‘volatile’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]
     setjmp(jb);
            ^~
```

Also, the specification of `setjmp` does not speak to whether it is saving the register values as they would be after setting the `jmp_buf` or before setting the `jmp_buf`.

If I need to be concerned about it, I can create a volatile copy of the `jmp_buf` and copy its contents around. But, I'd like to avoid that if it isn't required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it allowed to do longjmp() multiple times for one setjmp() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175221/is-it-allowed-to-do-longjmp-multiple-times-for-one-setjmp-call) tl;dr: you can reuse a jmp_buf , longjmp won't corrupt it.

Comment: @jthill Close. The question is is about non-local jumps, and so uses a global `jmp_buf`. See the comments below the accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the longjmp can't end the jmp_buf's lifetime and that's the only effect storage duration can have.

Comment: @jthill But the first comment literally says it doesn't apply to local variables. So the answer doesn't address the question, right?

Comment: You're going to have to read the standard and decide for yourself. If you read further into those comments you'll see people pointing out reasons to disbelieve the one you've latched on to. The idea that an object's possible future "death" might have some effect on its present value seems ... well, to be blunt, it strikes me as nonsense. setjmp is required to render the jmp_buf usable.

Comment: you can easily write your own [setjmp()/longjump()](https://github.com/user1095108/cr2) with exactly the behavior you want.

Comment: @jthill Your current position is significantly different from "this should be closed as a duplicate".

Comment: @user1095108: How much stack is a signal handler allowed to use?

Comment: I'm not seeing how the presence of a comment I think you should ignore because it's wrong changes anything else about that Q&A.

Comment: @jthill You said "You're going to have to read the standard and decide for yourself.", which I had already done before posting the question. I believe the question is unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>***TL;DR*** Since the standard isn't clear, it is better to treat the value of a local `jmp_buf` as indeterminate after a local `longjmp`.</kbd>

ISO/IEC 9899:2018 §17.13.1.1 ¶2 describes the behavior of `setjmp`, and ¶3 describes what happens on return.

> The `setjmp` macro saves its calling environment in its `jmp_buf` argument for later use by the `longjmp` function.
>
> ...
>
> If the return is from a direct invocation, the `setjmp` macro returns the value zero. If the return is from a call to the `longjmp` function, the `setjmp` macro returns a nonzero value.

We infer that a successful return from `setjmp` results in an initialized `jmp_buf` argument. However, there is no mention if the initialization takes into account of the `jmp_buf` itself having automatic storage duration (and so, itself could be represented by registers rather than by memory).

ISO/IEC 9899:2018 §7.13.2.1 ¶3 describes the behavior of `longjmp`, and is worded the same as the 2011 text cited by [Marko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72177016/315052):

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine<sup>254)</sup> have state,
> as of the time the `longjmp` function was called, except that the values of objects of automatic storage
> duration that are local to the function containing the invocation of the corresponding `setjmp` macro
> that do not have volatile-qualified type and have been changed between the `setjmp` invocation and
> `longjmp` call are indeterminate.
>
> ---
>
> <sub><sup>254)</sup>This includes, but is not limited to, the floating-point status flags and the state of open files.</sub>

However, the meaning of the word *between* is somewhat elusive. The standard could have explicitly specified the context of *between* to mean after `setjmp` completed. For example, the wording could have stated:

> ... changed between the `setjmp` ***return*** and `longjmp` call are indeterminate.

The current wording suggests that one should include the invocation of `setjmp` itself as something that may trigger the indeterminate condition.

There is a possibility that the semantics of the return of `longjmp` covers for this problem, however. ISO/IEC 9899:2018 §17.13.2.1 ¶4 states:

> After `longjmp` is completed, thread execution continues as if the corresponding invocation of the
> `setjmp` macro had just returned the value specified by `val`. ...

This sentence could be interpreted to mean that the invocation semantics of `setjmp` is the same whether it returns from direct invocation or returns from a `longjmp` function. That is, the return of `setjmp` means the `jmp_buf` argument is initialized and can be used by another `longjmp`. But again, this is not clear. In the most limiting interpretation, the *as if* clause only speaks to the value returned by `setjmp`, and not the invocation itself.

Since the semantics are ambiguous, it is proper to treat the `jmp_buf` object value as indeterminate upon return from `longjmp`.

Answer (score 2):

The [C11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section §7.13.2.1 point 3 states:

> All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine have state, as of the time the `longjmp` function was called, except that **the values of
> objects of automatic storage duration that are local to the function containing the
> invocation of the corresponding `setjmp` macro that do not have `volatile`-qualified type
> and have been changed between the `setjmp` invocation and `longjmp` call are
> indeterminate**.

Your `jmp_buf` object is not changed between `setjmp(jb)` and `longjmp(jb, ++i)`. The only variable which is changed between the calls is `i`, which is declared `volatile`, as the standard suggests.

So, to answer your question, `longjmp` cannot by itself "modify the contents of the local `jmp_buf` [in such a way] that would cause its contents to be undefined when `setjmp` returns", but modifying the `jmp_buf` between the two calls through other means could definitely cause trouble.

Comment: There are multiple ways to interpret "between", as it could be inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: @jxh IMHO there is exactly one sensible way to interpret that "between": the `setjmp()` call happens - a modification happens - the `longjmp()` call happens. Such a modification would be "between" the two calls. What happens *inside* the calls is none of the programmer's business. If library documentation tells me to *"not do X between the invocation of F and G"*, the only control I have is on *my code*; if F and G can break theirselves even if I follow the rule, then the library would be broken by design.

Comment: @jxh (one could also probably ask why on earth would anyone want to bother with `setjmp`/`longjmp` when you could just `goto local_label` in such scenario :P)

Comment: I can see a use case where the `longjmp` is actually embedded in some kind of error handling macro, and the error handler could be invoked locally to the function that issued `setjmp` or in some called function. The circumstances where the `jmp_buf` itself is local would be more farfetched, but could happen if it was embedded within a context data structure that is local variable to a thread start function.

Comment: This answer cannot be accepted as is, because it is missing an explanation of the semantics of `setjmp` with respect to what register state it has preserved. If it has preserved the state of registers prior to setting values in the `jmp_buf`, then it is possible that the `longjmp` ends up restoring the indeterminate values held by the buffer prior to the `setjmp` call.

Comment: @jxh existing standards define no such semantics, so I can't really materialize an explanation out of thin air. Both the C standard and the POSIX standard say the same thing, which is what I quote above. I added my own interpretation of what you deem "open to interpretation", but that's about it. As it currently stands, it seems that this is all you get unfortunately.

Comment: That is also my understanding, that the standard does not define what state actually gets preserved. Therefore, it seems possible that the state restored presents the uninitialized `jmp_buf`.

Comment: For your answer to hold, you should cite the *Returns* section for `longjmp`, which it describes the behavior should be *as if the corresponding invocation of the `setjmp` macro had just returned the value specified by `val`.* You might infer from this various things, but if it is as if `setjmp` is returning, then it should behave as if `setjmp` had finished initializing `jmp_buf`.

Comment: @jxh I don't see how quoting that helps to be honest.

Comment: I am offering you a suggestion that would make it feasible for me to accept your answer. There needs to be a justification that the state after `longjmp` presents an intact `jmp_buf` rather than one that was uninitialized.

Comment: @jxh I can see that, but don't see how *"After longjmp is completed, thread execution continues as if the corresponding invocation of the setjmp macro had just returned the value specified by val"* clarifies anything. You are concerned about whether or not the "between" should be inclusive or exclusive of the two function calls, and `longjmp()` is clearly not the problem here, as it merely reads `jmp_buf`; the problem is the initial `setjmp()`. If using a local non-volatile `jmp_buf` was illegal, then you'd already be breaking the rule at the first `setjmp()` invocation.

Comment: The inference of the *as if invocation of ... `setjmp` ... had just returned* is that upon return, the specified behavior, that `setjmp` presents an initialized `jmp_buf`, is the effect after `longjmp`. Because it is returning as if it had been invoked.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine.

On a related note, you don't need `volatile` on `i` because it's assigned to by `setjmp()`.

On a very careful reading of the man page for `longjmp()` and my copy of K&R C, the contents of `jb` are only invalid within the body of your function, meaning if there were a second call to `longjmp()`, it would see a valid view of `jb`. Under the resaonable assumption that valid code does not become invalid in newer standard versions, this will still apply today.

TL;DR you don't need to mark variables of type `jmp_buf` volatile.

Comment: Tagging `jmp_buf` as volatile caused compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: @jxh: I'm checking my docs to see if volatile can be omitted.